# How to proof that if $(H,*) $ is nontrivial normal subgroup of $G,*)$ and both $(H,*)$ and $(G/H,\otimes)$ are solvable then $(G,*)$ is solvable?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(H,*)$ be a nontrivial normal subgroup of $G,*)$.

if $(H,*)$ and $(G/H,\otimes)$ are solvable, how to proof that $(G,*)$ is solvable?

Comment: Is $H$ supposed to be normal and $(G/H, \otimes)$ the usual quotient group? If so, then what have you tried so far?

Comment: @JendrikStelzner, yes.

Comment: You may use the derived series $G^{(n)}$.

First recall that
$$
(G/H)^{(n)} = G^{(n)} H/ H.
$$
So if $G/H$ is solvable, there is $N$ such that $G^{(N)} \le H$.

Now $H$ is solvable as well, so there is $M$ such that $H^{(M)} = 1$.

It follows that
$$
G^{(N+M)} \le H^{(M)} = 1,
$$
so that $G$ is solvable.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti, Is there another way to proof this than using the  derived series?

Comment: @Jake, please tell me which definition of solvable group you would like to be used.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti, this definition is what I understand. http://i.imgur.com/YC1uvWp.png

Comment: Then all you need is the correspondence theorem. The relevant subnormal series in $G/H$ is made of subgroups of groups $G_{i}/H$, where $H \le G_{i}$, The fact that $G_{i}/H$ is normal in $G_{i+1}/H$ is equivalent to $G_{i}$ normal in $G_{i+1}$, and then $(G_{i+1}/H) / (G_{i}/H) \cong G_{i+1}/G_{i}$.